# preg_match don't match right

Tags: php, curl, preg-match

I've been trying to parse with php preg_match the source code of this website http://www.nzz.ch/aktuell/zuerich/stadt_region/notrufdienst-am-handgelenk-1.18068637 for days without success. The reading has gone well with curl and the search for the title too.

In the search for the description with preg_match something goes wrong.
`preg_match('/Description" content="(.*)">/i', $content, $description);
$ogdescription = substr($description[0], 22, -1);`

The result of this search is:

```
Ein Telefon nützt wenig, wenn es sich im Notfall nicht in greifbarer Nähe befindet. Das haben sich die Gründer der Firma Limmex gedacht und eine Armbanduhr auf den Markt gebracht, die per Knopfdruck zum Mobiltelefon wird." /&gt;<meta name="Publisher" content="Neue Zürcher Zeitung AG, Switzerland"><meta name="email" content="online.redaktion@nzz.ch"><meta name="copyright" content="Copyright &amp;copy; 2013 Neue Zürcher Zeitung AG, Switzerland, http://www.nzz.ch/agb"><meta http-equiv="content-language" content="de"><meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"><meta name="Author" content="Impressum Neue Zürcher Zeitung, Switzerland, http://www.nzz.ch/impressum"><meta name="distribution" content="global"><meta name="robots" content="index, follow, noarchive, noodp"><meta name="revisit-after" content="1 hour"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"><meta property="fb:app_id" content="138008459595436"><meta property="og:title" content="Zürcher Jungunternehmen: Notrufdienst am Handgelenk - Übersicht Nachrichten - NZZ.ch"><meta property="og:type" content="article"><meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nzz.ch/aktuell/zuerich/stadt_region/notrufdienst-am-handgelenk-1.18068637"><meta property="og:image" content="http://images.nzz.ch/app.php/eos/v2/image/view/145/-/lead/25b76387/1.18068643.1366564054.jpg"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Neue Zürcher Zeitung"><meta name="viewport" content="width=1390"><meta name="application-name" content="NZZ Online"><meta name="msapplication-tooltip" content="Start NZZ Online in Site Mode"><meta name="msapplication-starturl" content="http://www.nzz.ch"><meta name="msapplication-window" content="width=1024;height=760"><meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#000000"><meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Nachrichten; action-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/nachrichten; icon-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/favicon.ico"><meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Finanzen; action-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/finanzen; icon-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/favicon.ico"><meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Magazin; action-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/magazin; icon-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/favicon.ico"><meta name="msapplication-task" content="name=Marktplätze; action-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/marktplaetze; icon-uri=http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/favicon.ico"><link href="http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/favicon.ico"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://www.nzz.ch/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"><link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/118094012157733055567"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection, handheld, print" href="/bundles/website/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"><title>Zürcher Jungunternehmen: Notrufdienst am Handgelenk - Übersicht Nachrichten - NZZ.ch</title><link rel="canonical" href="http://www.nzz.ch/aktuell/zuerich/stadt_region/notrufdienst-am-handgelenk-1.18068637"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/version-2.8.1/css/6927630.css"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="/version-2.8.1/css/5bd0678.css"><meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="false"><link rel="search" href="/search" title="Suche Neue Zürcher Zeitung, Switzerland, http://www.nzz.ch/search"><link rel="author" href="/impressum" title="Impressum Neue Zürcher Zeitung, Switzerland, http://www.nzz.ch/impressum"><link rel="copyright" href="/agb" title="Copyright &amp;copy; 2013 Neue Zürcher Zeitung AG, Switzerland, http://www.nzz.ch/agb"><!--[if lt IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src="/version-2.8.1/bundles/website/js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]--><!-- Maxymiser script start --><!-- Maxymiser script end -->
```

What I have done wrong, that takes it all the source code?

---

The next problem:

```
preg_match('/escription" content="(.*?)" \/>/i', $content, $description);
```

$ogdescription = $description[1];

```
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Am 17 .4. 2013 besch&auml;ftigte sich das &Ouml;1-Gesundheitsmagazin mit Pers&ouml;nlicher Assistenz und dem Recht auf Selbstbestimmung.">
```

Why don't match it?

Comment: it is better to use DOMDocument For this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match('/Description" content="(.*?)" \/>/i', $content, $description);
```

Make your search 'non-greedy' note the '?' added to your regex

Without the ? the regex will match to the last > symbol it finds.  With the ? it will stop at the first one after a match.

You will also need the escaped forward slash and the space as the content is xHTML.

With this regex

```
$description[0] // will contain the full matched tag
$description[1] // will contain just the text from inside the tag
```

Comment: thanks. this is the solution: '/Description" content="(.*?)" \/>/i'

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help.  If solves your problem, please can you mark it as answered, so people see it as answered and it helps future users of the site :)

Comment: The next problem:

preg_match('/escription" content="(.*?)" \/>/i', $content, $description);
$ogdescription = $description[1];

<meta name="twitter:description" content="Am 17 .4. 2013 besch&auml;ftigte sich das &Ouml;1-Gesundheitsmagazin mit Pers&ouml;nlicher Assistenz und dem Recht auf Selbstbestimmung.">
Why don't match it?

Comment: Its a slightly different match.  That one isn't xHTML so doesn't need the /> on the end. If you want to match both with the same regex you will need `Description" content="(.*?)"\s?\/?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/Description" content="(.*)"/i', $content, $description);   
$ogdescription = substr($description[0], 22, -1);
```

no need match >

or

```
preg_match('/Description" content="(.*?)" \/>/i', $a, $description); 
print_r($description); // use $description[1]

Array
(
    [0] => Description" content="Ein Telefon nützt wenig, wenn es sich im Notfall nicht in greifbarer Nähe befindet. Das haben sich die Gründer der Firma Limmex gedacht und eine Armbanduhr auf den Markt gebracht, die per Knopfdruck zum Mobiltelefon wird." />
    [1] => Ein Telefon nützt wenig, wenn es sich im Notfall nicht in greifbarer Nähe befindet. Das haben sich die Gründer der Firma Limmex gedacht und eine Armbanduhr auf den Markt gebracht, die per Knopfdruck zum Mobiltelefon wird.
)
```

Comment: thanks. this is the solution: '/Description" content="(.*?)" \/>/i'